# What options are their to turn off a function in update() of Unity for brief periods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an function in `Update()` that polls for user input.

Every now and then, for very brief periods of time (during player character teleportation) I want to turn off that polling of input so that nothing extraneous or weird happens when the player is re-presented at the teleported location.

The function doing the input polling is named `GetAndSetInputStates()` and sets a bunch of booleans based on input.

What ways can I use to switch this function off, for a couple of frames or maybe three or four, at the most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `bool` to true when the teleportation starts and set it to false when it ends. Make a if statement in your update function to not call the `GetAndSetInputStates()`. That would be the easier answer. A more complex but better answer would be to use a state pattern that implement the `GetAndSetInputStates` and change the state object to a object that just returns nothing when there's a transformation.

Comment: Thank you!! First will do for now. Immediate solve. Can you give me the terms I need to search for more about this state pattern in Unity and C#? I'm easily...

Comment: Here is a link to an question and answer on state pattern in C# https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/343955/is-this-a-good-way-to-implement-state-pattern

And here is a link to C# design patterns that has the state pattern http://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern

The look terms would be `C# state design pattern`